# how to perform action on these tabBar items in ios

Tags: ios, uitabbar

```
[items addObject:[[UITabBarItem alloc]
                      initWithTitle:@" Add Contacts" image:[UIImage imageNamed:@"images.jpeg"] selectedImage:[UIImage imageNamed : @"checkBox.jpeg"]]];

[items addObject:[[UITabBarItem
                       alloc]initWithTitle:@"Contacts" image:[UIImage imageNamed:@"images.jpeg"] selectedImage:[UIImage imageNamed : @"checkBox.jpeg"]]];
```

Answer (score 0):

You can't directly add selectors to `UITabBarItem`.

You can achieve the functionality through [- (void)tabBar:(UITabBar *)tabBar didSelectItem:(UITabBarItem *)item](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/DOCUMENTATION/UIKit/Reference/UITabBarDelegate_Protocol/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/intfm/UITabBarDelegate/tabBar%3adidSelectItem%3a) delegate method.

Add `tags` to your `UITabBarItem` and implement the delegate method like:

```
- (void)tabBar:(UITabBar *)tabBar didSelectItem:(UITabBarItem *)item
{
    if(item.tag == yourTag)
    {
        // so your stuff here
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

We need to implement **UITabBarControllerDelegate** method if we are using ***UITabBarController***.

```
- (void)tabBarController:(UITabBarController *)tabBarController didSelectViewController:(UIViewController *)viewController;
```

Answer (score 0):

Set up uitabbarviewcontroller in storyboard and define particular class.
Each tabbar set index in inspector field uitabbarviewcontroller.

Then initial view controller in viewdidload method write this code.

I think helpful this code.

```
UITabBar *tabBar = self.tabBarController.tabBar;
UITabBarItem *item0 = [tabBar.items objectAtIndex:0];

[item0 setTitle:@"Home"];
[item0 setFinishedSelectedImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"home_btn_hred.png"] withFinishedUnselectedImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"home_btn.png"]];
[item0 setTitleTextAttributes:[NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:
                               [UIColor darkGrayColor], UITextAttributeTextColor,
                               nil] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
[item0 setTitleTextAttributes:[NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:
                               [UIColor redColor], UITextAttributeTextColor,
                               nil] forState:UIControlStateSelected];
```